# How to enable power saving features for the i915 kernel module?

Tags: drivers, kernel, i915

According to [this post on Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dell_XPS_15_9560#Enable_power_saving_features_for_the_i915_kernel_module) the i915 kernel module has options which result in significant power savings.

How to "pass" the following options to the i915 kernel module?

`enable_fbc=1 enable_psr=1 disable_power_well=0`

Comment: Did you test them?  (by putting them on your `linux` (kernel) line in grub, ie. pressing <E> to edit it, adding them & then press <F10> to boot with those entries added...

Comment: @guiverc That's pretty cool, didn't know about that but followed instructions and the options have been loaded in. Is the correct way to set the options permanently to edit them in [/etc/default/grub](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19486)?

Comment: Yep - here is a reference link if you'd like more info (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters); which includes the useful hint to `sudo update-grub` to cause re-build your grub file after you've edited.